# Api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0.dll - Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (vc_redist.x64.exe and vcredist_x86.exe) fails to install

Tags: c#, c++, windows, visual-studio-2015, redistributable

After probably the installation of an outdated program messsed up some libraries, the window "Missing Api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0.dll" popped when starting particular programs.

As solution the installation of "Microsoft Visual C++ 2015 Redistributable (vc_redist.x64.exe and vcredist_x86.exe)" is recommended. However, this installation permanently failed.

Also the installation of Visual Studio 2015 itself failed, because the necesssary KB2999226 also faild to install. Manual installation of KB2999226

```
wusa.exe Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu /extract:XXXX
```

DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:XXXX\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.cab

seemed to work (package successfuly added) but did not help. Visual Studio 2015 and vc_redist.x64.exe failed to install.

Comment: Don't put answers in the question, or [solved] in the title; if you have answered the question yourself, *write an actual answer*.

Comment: This problem cost me a workday. I spent extra time to sign up here and to share the solution, so that others benefit from it. Do you think that rating such efforts as unhelpful encourags others to share there solutions as well?

Comment: Perhaps not. It seems to have encouraged you to do at least half the job of fixing it, though.

Comment: Sending a message or a comment would have been a better way to achive that. We all do that to help others and we do that voluntarily. It's not motivating to be downrated just when tryong to help.

Comment: ...I *did* comment, not that anyone's required to do so. If you want to avoid down votes, read the material in the Help Center *before* posting.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what finally helped: Re-Installation of SP 1 for Windows 7.

As a matter of fact my system already had SP 1 for Win 7 installed. But obviously some fixes seemded to be broken. Re-Installation (Repair) of SP 1 for Win 7 helpd. After that, KB2999226 still did not install, but vc_redist.x64.exe and vcredist_x86.exe did and the "Api-ms-win-core-crt-l1-1-0.dll" problem disappeared.

To be on the safe side try this:

```
Re-Install SP 1 for Win 7
manually install KB2999226
```

wusa.exe Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.msu /extract:XXXX DISM.exe /Online /Add-Package /PackagePath:XXXX\Windows6.1-KB2999226-x64.cab

```
Repair: vc_redist.x64.exe and vcredist_x86.exe
```

If that doesn't work just try steps 1. and 3. (leave manual installation of KB2999226 out)

Comment: *"If that doesn't work just try steps 1. and 3."* - so why include step 2? Do you know how, why or even *if* these steps actually solve the problem?